# VBA: Possible to call a worksheet using a string?

Tags: string, vba, excel

I have a macro that I would like to use several (>20) times, but each time it needs to reference a different worksheet. For example, if my sheets are named S1, S2, S3, etc., for one particular use of the macro, it needs to call S2.

I've tried defining a public string as "Public CS As String" and then nesting the macros to achieve the goal (without copying and pasting the entire macro 20+ times).

For example,

```
Sub Macro_2()

    CS = "S2"

    Macro

End Sub
```

However, I get an error message, "Subscripts out of range" referring to this line of code in the main macro where I call the desired worksheet:

```
Sheets(" 'CS' ").Select
```

I appreciate the help!!!

Comment: You must use, as above, `Sheets(CS).Select`, or, if you don't wanna use a variable, `Sheets("S2").Select`.

Comment: Beware: there is no guarantee that sheet `"Si"` corresponds to index `i`... If you just take this for granted, than you may get unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1):

Um.. Parameters?

```
public sub YourMacro(byval SheetName as string)
   Sheets(SheetName).select
end sub

Sub Macro_2() 
  YourMacro "S2"
End Sub
```

Comment: yes yes yes! ... and best to have the names in a list on a seperate sheet and work from there, so you can change it at any time without touching the code

Answer (score 0):

You can write a subroutine that calls your macro for all your sheets like this:

```
Sub ProcessAllSheets()

    numberOfSheets = 10 ' Or whatever

    ' Loop through all sheets
    For i = 1 To numberOfSheets
        sheetName = "S" & i ' sheetName will be "S1" when i=1, "S2" when i=2 etc.
        Call Macro_2(sheetName)
    Next i

End Sub
```

or just one sheet at a time:

```
Sub ProcessOneSheet()
    sheetName = "S7"
    Call Macro_2(sheetName)
End Sub
```

Your macro will need a small edit to accept the `sheetName` argument:

```
Sub Macro_2(sheetName)
    ' Macro_2 is not a very useful name...
    ' Call it something more descriptive!

    CS = sheetName
    ' CS isn't a very good variable name either...
    ' Why not just replace CS with e.g. sheetName

    'Macro code goes here...

End Sub
```

NB: Most programmers will advise you to generally stay away from `Public` variables, unless you specifically know that this is the best way to solve your problem (which it isn't in your case). `Public` a.k.a. global variables often result in hard-to-find bugs.